# Recommend distribution for Graphic Design

Tags: ubuntu, distribution-choice, distributions, graphics

I'm new here.
I need for a `Linux Distribution` for my girlfriend, to install on her computer (in a `VM`, to be more exactly).

She studies Graphic Design, and she use to work on `Windows XP`, but she got problems with License and other stuffs (also, her machine is a little older), so a proffesor on her University recommended her to work on Linux.

I do some research and I found `Ubuntu Lucid Lynx` [here](http://www.linoob.com/2010/07/ubuntu-studio-10-04-lucid-lynx/), and it looks like it will work for her.
I've seen the tools that the distro has, but I don't know how useful are. She works a lot with `Photoshop` and `Illustrator` as far as I know, but she could use some other tools..
The question is, is this the best choice for an SO oriented to graphic Design?
Better a newest version, or an older ? What other tools she can get on this distro ?
Are another option better? 
Also, about the requerimients, she has a Pentium IV and 2 GB RAM (a little older). I don't remember how much free space disk she has.. Is this a recommended version, or a newest will work better ?

Comment: I think your girlfriend will be happier with a Mac. Unix goodness for you, Adobe friendliness for her.

Comment: It's an option for the future maybe, but right now there is now money to buy a computer. Thanks anyway

Comment: note that Ubuntu Lucid is a couple of years old. probably the oldest you should get is the latest LTS, 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much any recent distro should do: they all are able to run GIMP and Inkscape (the main Photoshop and Illustrator alternatives for Linux).

But they might not run very well on a Pentium 4. You might want to try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), which provides a lighter desktop environment while keeping the Ubuntu structure. (Other lightweight distros like Arch Linux exist, but they have a tougher learning curve)

Comment: thanks! So in Xubuntu she can run GIMP and Inkscape? Also, do you know another tools for graphic design?

Comment: Yes, she can. For other graphics design apps you might want to take a look at the tools shipped with the [Fedora Design Suite](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/design/#about) and with [Ubuntu Studio](https://staging.ubuntustudio.org/tour/graphics/).

Comment: GIMP and Inkscape are some very powerful tools for dealing with raster and vector graphics, respectively.  However, GIMP is primarily a image editor.  If you want to have a good image *painting* application, you may want to check out [Krita](http://www.krita.org/).  Fair warning: Krita is KDE-only, so you may either want to get a distribution with KDE on it (Kubuntu) or install KDE on whatever disto you use.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu has dedicated version for graphic designers and Multimedia artists. Try [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)

Comment: Hey good recommendation but someone (@Renan) mentioned that in the other answer.

Comment: Nice suggestion. There's also the [OpenArtist](http://openartisthq.org/) distro, which might be worth looking into. Looks like a release was put out just a few days ago (27 Jan 2014).

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) is a good choice. Although any Linux with the right [software](http://ubuntustudio.org/tour/graphics/) can get you started fast.

Here is a one line command for the Ubuntu terminal that would give you everything you need:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gimp inkscape icc-profiles-free imagemagick gmic gimp-plugin-registry gimp-gmic gimp-ufraw gimp-data-extras fontforge darktable
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with Linux. The real problem is that the hardware is weak and can not run the latest versions of Adobe software but you can use the [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) program